# Three.js use multiple materials on one mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe, 8thwall-web

I am trying to understand how to add multiple materials to a mesh. I want to take the existing material and apply another slightly transparent material to my existing mesh. Right now, passing it as an array it just disappears. I know I am missing something, just not sure what that is. The end goal is so I can animate the opacity of the new material in/out over the existing one.

**Original Material**

```
const originalMaterial = child.material.clone();
```

**New Material**

```
const newMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
 name: 'New Mat',
 map: newTexture,
 emissiveMap: newTextureMap,
 side: THREE.DoubleSide,
 opacity: .5,
 transparent: true
});
```

**Combining them**

```
child.material = [originalMaterial, newMaterial]
child.material.needsUpdate = true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebGL doesn't allow for multiple materials on a single mesh. That's why the `THREE.Mesh` constructor [only allows one geometry, and one material](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Mesh).

To do what you want, you could create two meshes, with one material's transparency set to 0.5. But more frequently you would just use a single mesh, and assign variations in opacity [through the `.alphaMap` texture](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.alphaMap). This would give you more flexibility because you can have many more transparency values on a single object, without having to create new materials for each:

```
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var alphaTexture = textureLoader.load("path/to/alpha.png");
mesh.material.alphaMap = alphaTexture;

mesh.material.transparent = true; // <- don't forget this!
```

Comment: That's a great idea! I will give that a go on my other model that I am trying to achieve this on.

For now, I was able to clone my mesh and add my new material to that and fade the cloned mesh in/out and that is doing the trick.